# Why I get "System.ArgumentException: The path is not of a legal form." when using the webview2 to initialize the browser

Tags: c#

Below is the error:

See the end of this message for details on invoking
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

**Exception Text**

> System.ArgumentException: The path is not of a legal form.
> at System.IO.Path.LegacyNormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)
> at System.IO.Path.InternalGetDirectoryName(String path)
> at Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2Environment.LoadWebView2LoaderDll()
> at Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2Environment.d__3.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.WebView2.d__23.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at ECLautomation.Form1.d__150.MoveNext() in xxx\Form1.cs:line xxx
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at ECLautomation.Form1.<Form1_Load>d__149.MoveNext() in xxx\Form1.cs:line xxx
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()

And below is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core;
using Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms;

namespace WinFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private static readonly string indexUrl = "http://www.moodys.com";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await InitializeAsync(webView21);
        }

        public async Task InitializeAsync(WebView2 webView21)
        {
            CoreWebView2Environment webView2Environment = null;
            await webView21.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(webView2Environment);
        }

        private void webView21_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted(object sender, CoreWebView2InitializationCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            webView21.CoreWebView2.Navigate(indexUrl);
        }

        private void webView21_NavigationCompleted(object sender, CoreWebView2NavigationCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            string url = webView21.CoreWebView2.Source.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(url);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool res = IsLogin();

            if (res == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please login Moody's");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Successful");
                webView21.CoreWebView2.Navigate("https://www.moodys.com/search?keyword=annual%20default%20study%20excel&searchfrom=GS");
                WaitForSeconds(10);
                SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}");
                SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");

                MessageBox.Show("Annual Default Study file downloaded, please close the popup edge browser.");

                WaitForSeconds(10);
                webView21.CoreWebView2.Navigate("https://www.moodys.com/search?keyword=Sovereign%20Default%20And%20Recovery%20Rates%20excel%20data&searchfrom=GS");
                WaitForSeconds(10);
                SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}");
                SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");

                MessageBox.Show("Sovereign file downloaded, please close the popup edge browser.");
            }
        }

        public static void WaitForSeconds(int seconds)
        {
            DateTime startTime;
            DateTime endTime;
            startTime = DateTime.Now;
            for (int i = 0; ; i++)
            {
                endTime = DateTime.Now;
                TimeSpan difference = endTime - startTime;
                if (difference.TotalSeconds < seconds)
                {
                    Application.DoEvents();
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        private bool IsLogin()
        {
            var js = @"document.documentElement.innerText.indexOf('Sign In or Register');";
            int res = Convert.ToInt32(ExecuteScript(js));
            return res >= 1;
        }

        private string ExecuteScript(string javaScript)
        {
            var taskAwaiter = webView21.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync(javaScript).GetAwaiter();
            WaitAsyncTask(5, taskAwaiter);
            return taskAwaiter.GetResult();
        }

        public void WaitAsyncTask(int waitSecond, System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter<string> activeTask)
        {
            DateTime WaitStartTime = DateTime.Now;
            double secondDiffer = (DateTime.Now - WaitStartTime).TotalSeconds;
            while (secondDiffer < waitSecond)
            {
                secondDiffer = (DateTime.Now - WaitStartTime).TotalSeconds;
                Application.DoEvents();
                if (activeTask.IsCompleted)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

I want to initialise my browser and wait for the download, but an error occurs on this part

```
CoreWebView2Environment webView2Environment = null;
await webView21.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(webView2Environment);
```

Are there anything wrong in this part? Thanks.

Comment: Which line of your code is "xxx\Form1.cs:line xxx"?

Comment: Line 26 and 32, which is the await webView21.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(webView2Environment); and await InitializeAsync(webView21);